# Conditions when didFinishLaunchingWithOptions not called?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I'm putting all my database setup code in `application.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but it seems something is randomly accessing the database before that according to crash reports.

Are there scenarios where `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not called, such as launching from a push notification or location update? Or is there something else besides `willFinish` that is called?

Comment: when app is in background and launched by tap. But in case of push or local notification if app is in background then only didFinishLaunchingWithOptions won't get called. Please check the case of background app refresh if u have enabled.

Comment: are you sure it's before `application.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? Maybe it's still in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` block, but just that the crash is **before** you log your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?